# Publish only iOS app with sdk 3.1?

Tags: ios, publish, facebook-ios-sdk

I want my app to just be able to let users post a message on Facebook. Seems like with the new requirement in sdk 3.1 that apps open a session first with read only permissions and then re-authorize for write permissions this becomes impossible or extremely ugly as it forces two app switches.

My scenario is I have a post-to-Facebook button in my app, I want the user to be able to post a message to Facebook. He is not logged in yet at this time.

If I use the new +openSessionWithPublishPermissions:... Method I get an sdk error stating apps are required to login with read only permissions.

If I use the +openSessionsWithReadPermissions:... I get an app switch to authorize, then I use the reauthoruzeSessionWithPublishPermissions I get another app switch. So pressing the button results in two app switches, which is the extremely ugly case.

This new restrictions on permissions would break a number of the apps in the Facebook sdk demo, which continue to work only because they use old deprecated methods.

I can achieve this using the new ios6 Facebook API with two short falls, it doesn't work for iOS 5 users and it only works if the user is logged in at the system level but doesn't allow the user to be logged in just to my app.

Answer (score 0):

I guess in that case you'll need to use deprecated method `openActiveSessionWithPermissions` to disable the native Auth Dialog.

See Tip 5 at [Facebook developer "howto"](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/ios-6/)